# Ctrl+Click or Right-Click on web-sites with Chrome?

Tags: events, google-chrome, click

I have a web application, which works fine with Firefox and IE, but in Webkit browsers like Chrome it doesn't.

There are two click events, this application uses, which don't work with Chrome:

- `Ctrl + Left-Click` for selecting records in a table
- `Right-Click` for opening a contextual menu

It's like the click events don't get fired at all...

Comment: You shouldn't be using `Ctrl + ...` modifiers, as they could be intercepted by the browser, or the OS.

Comment: Yes, I didn't had this stupid idea, I just have to maintain this application :\ One step will probably be removing the `ctrl + ` and replacing it with a normal click, but what about the right click?

Comment: you have no yet accepted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Right click:

```
document.body.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev) { 
    alert('show your custom context menu'); 
    return false; 
}, false);
```

---

### Ctrl + Left click:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    if(ev.ctrlKey) {
        alert('select single table cell');
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

its better to use Jquery to be honesty, i prefer something like this to catch a right click  and escape from  browser compatibility issues

```
$('#elementtobeClicked').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
            alert('Left mouse button ?');
            break;
        case 2:
            alert('Middle mouse button ?');
            break;
        case 3:
            alert('Right mouse button ?');
            break;
        default:
            alert('You have a micky mouse !');
    }
});
```

or

```
$('#elementtobeClicked').bind("contextmenu",function(e){
   alert('Context Menu ?');
   return false;
});
```

have some good time over jquery

have to  go through
    **event.shiftKey &&  event.ctrlKey**